# Navigation bar moving with content

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I have ran into a problem, i can't seem to find something similar to this.

My navigation bar is in the `header`.
My page content is in the `body`, with a `div` called `.page-content`.

When I move my content with `margin-top`, so it moves away from the navbar, the navbar follows. While they are not in the same class or anything. Is there something I might be doing wrong?

[image]

The Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #5d585d;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
nav {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  height: 25px;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}
nav {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.page-content {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.page-content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
}
.page-content p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.dropdownmenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #b4efed;
  color: #2a6d85;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #cbfffd;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbarheader">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">OVER MIJ</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>



  </nav>
</header>

<div class="page-content">

  <p>TEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT
    TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT
  </p>


</div>
```

Comment: You should provide your HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks, haven't figured out how to insert good code blocks. So i had to put alot of spaces for it to work, that's why i did not do it.

Comment: Added the HTML / CSS / PHP files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using `position:fixed` in `header` you need to set `padding-top` in `.page-content`

If you don't need it to be `fixed` then just remove that property.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #5d585d;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  height: 25px;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none
}
.page-content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 65px; /* new */
  width: 50%;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
}
.page-content p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.dropdownmenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #b4efed;
  color: #2a6d85;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #cbfffd;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbarheader">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">OVER MIJ</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="page-content">
  <p>TEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT
    TEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXTTEST TEXT
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Done! Very new to stackoverflow, so i'm getting used to all the things around here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want the navbar to stay on top of page...if so then:
Try this..
`header { position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 60px; background-color: #5d585d; border: 5px yellow solid; }`

And you can try to eliminate these two:
`/* nav {
margin-top: 0px;
} */

```
 /* nav {
      margin-top: 0px;
    } */`
```